# Convert standard 360-degree to atan2

Tags: math, angle, degrees, radians, atan2

I need to reverse calculation of standard 360 angle to atan2.

It's my standard angle calulation

```
Standard angle =  (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y,x));

if(angle < 0)
  angle += 360;
```

I need Math.atan2 value from angle how to achieve that.

Comment: And what result do you want? Two coordinates or angle in range -Pi..Pi?

Comment: need angle in range.

Comment: "need angle in range": this sentence is.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is this Java? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To translate degrees range `0..360` into radians range `-Pi..Pi`:

```
if(angle > 180)
   angle -= 360;
angle_radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
```

If your angle may be beyond standard range (you did not mentioned this), use integer modulo instead of loops

```
angle = angle % 360
```

(check how modulo operator works with negative numbers in your language)

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is not very clear, it seems that you want to retrieve the angle before the statement

```
if (angle < 0)
  angle += 360;
```

As `atan2` returns a value in the range `[-π,π)`, i.e. `[-180°,180°)`, the subrange `[-180°,0°)` is mapped to `[180°,360°)`. Then you invert with

```
if (angle >= 180°)
  angle-= 360;
```

You also need to convert back to radians.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution with O(1) performance:

```
double generalModulus(double value, double modulus, double offset) {
    return value - Math.floor((value-offset)/modulus) * modulus + offset;
}

double normalizeAngleDegrees(double angleInDegrees, double offset) {
    return generalModulus(angleInDegrees, 360.0, offset);
}

double normalizeAngleRadians(double angleInRadians, double offset) {
    return generalModulus(angleInRadians, 2.0*Math.PI, offset);
}
```

To use:

```
double normDeg = normalizeAngleDegrees(angle, -180); // produces angle in range [-180, 180)
double normRad = normalizeAngleRadians(angle, 0); // produces angle in range [0, 2*Pi)
```

Answer (score -1):

My Own answer

```
int normalizeAngle(int angle)
{
    int newAngle = angle;
    while (newAngle <= -180) newAngle += 360;
    while (newAngle > 180) newAngle -= 360;
    return newAngle;
}
```

Comment: Look at my addition